# checking the value of checkbox dynamically in runtime using "if" loop and performing operations

Tags: excel, vba

I've a excel vba code. I will have a userform and populate the userform with ckeckboxes during runtime getting the data from the spreadsheet. Now when i click the OK buton i need the code to check the values of the checkboxes. If any checkbox is checked then correspondingly it should peform some operations. I have used "IF" loop. But the code doesn't go to the IF loop. it just skips it. I have the sample code below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
lastrow = Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row
For idx = 1 To latrow
    If Me.Controls("cname" & idx).Value = True Then
        'my code
    End If
Next idx
UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub selectall()
Dim idx As Integer
lastrow = Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row - 4
Dim chk As Control
For idx = 1 To lastrow
    Me.Controls("cname" & idx).Value = True
Next idx
End Sub

Private Sub userform_initialize()
Dim idx As Integer
lastrow = Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row - 4
Dim EachLabel As Integer
Dim cCntrl As Control

    Dim chk As Control
    Dim tbindex As Integer
    For idx = 1 To lastrow

            Set chk1 = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.checkbox.1", "cname" & idx, True)
            chk1.Caption = Cells(4 + idx, 4).Value
            chk1.Visible = True
            chk1.Left = 6
            chk1.Top = 1 + idx * 17.5
            chk1.Width = 100
            chk1.Height = 15.75

    Next
UserForm1.Frame1.ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
UserForm1.Frame1.ScrollHeight = 20 * lastrow
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in line 3: "latrow", not "lastrow". Try setting `Option Explicit` at the top of your code - although it forces you to declare variables, which is extra work, it does catch errors like this.